# Dash Table top right cell automatically selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

When I try to upload a file using a dash table the top right cell is automatically selected. This is actually a bit of an issue since this selection happens under other circumstances (like changing to a different tab and then back).

This means that the screen will automatically move to that table when returning to the tab which makes it quite hard to use. It can be repliacted by taking the code from https://github.com/plotly/dash-recipes/blob/master/upload-data-to-table.py and just adding a second tab. The top right cell will always be selected.

Its like it has the autofocus Attribute (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

Have tried it on different browsers and it always occurs expect on Internet Explorer. The fact that it works properly on Internet Explorer and not on other browsers makes me uncomfortable but could indicate that Internet Explorer lacks the ability to do the wrong thing.

Many thanks